# Flask POST API with angular api calling

Tags: python-3.x, angular

I have front end in angular from there I'm calling my flask POST API :

```
controllerForm = new FormGroup({
    name: new FormControl(''),
    id: new FormControl(''),
    address: new FormControl(''),
    port: new FormControl(''),
    ctrl_id: new FormControl(''),
});

this.httpClient.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/controllers/update/', {
  ctrl_id:this.controllerForm.value.ctrl_id,
  port:this.controllerForm.value.port,
  address:this.controllerForm.value.address,
  id:this.controllerForm.value.id,
  name:this.controllerForm.value.name

}).subscribe(data => console.log(data))
```

At flask API Side I have written this code:

```
from flask_restful import Api
app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

class CtrlUpdate(Resource):
"""Update."""

    def post(self):
        """Controller update."""
        import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        return jsonify({'status': True})

api.add_resource(CtrlUpdate, '/controllers/update')
```

But I'm couldn't able to reach to the post method getting error of 405 not allowed
Getting some issue at angular in calling POST API.

Comment: Does the `api` have url prefix set?

Comment: I couldn't get you. I'm new to this

Comment: No worries. Could you please add `api` variable definition to the question?

Comment: `api`. See how you call `api.add_resource()` - you probably have this `api` variable defined prior to that.

Comment: did you tested your API using POSTMAN???

Comment: @VickyGill yes, its working on POSTMAN, but through angular its giving 405 not allowed error

Comment: try with http.any  in angular & then check method at Server side which method is coming

Comment: I'm get this `"OPTIONS /controllers/update/ HTTP/1.1" 200`

Comment: issue is from Angular side , Angular is not sending POST method to Server

Comment: Pass Headers in Angular side application/json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
controllerForm = new FormGroup({
    name: new FormControl(''),
    id: new FormControl(''),
    address: new FormControl(''),
    port: new FormControl(''),
    ctrl_id: new FormControl(''),
});

this.httpClient.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/controllers/update', {
  ctrl_id:this.controllerForm.value.ctrl_id,
  port:this.controllerForm.value.port,
  address:this.controllerForm.value.address,
  id:this.controllerForm.value.id,
  name:this.controllerForm.value.name

}).subscribe(data => console.log(data))
```

Remove Slash from end of your API URL , because Flask routing doesn't allow

Comment: Still getting method not allowed ??

Comment: @app.route('/controllers/update/', methods=['POST'])

Also Add routing in Flask API like this

Comment: Remove slash from last this.httpClient.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/controllers/update/', {

Comment: OMG it works Thank you so much.. `http://127.0.0.1:5000/controllers/update`